# Issue with scraping data and implementing relationships for my database

Tags: database, database-design, scrape

I'm trying to make a better 'handbook' for a university I attend. Here's what's currently on [offer](http://monash.edu/pubs/2014handbooks/units/) and where I'm trying to get my data from.

Initially scraping everything was pretty trivial. What I have at the moment is 425 course titles and 5255 subject codes and names in a database. Problem being I'm stuck as to how to programatically implement the relationships degree -> unit.

What's making it difficult is that the current handbook is pretty hard to navigate and I'm having trouble coming up with a solution to scrape the information I need.

Any one have any ideas?

My goal is to have a portal where someone enters what degree they're studying and at what level, and are then presented with the units they can take.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Typically degrees of various levels are offered by faculties.

Here pages for ["areas of study"](http://monash.edu/pubs/2014handbooks/aos/search) by [faculty](http://www.monash.edu/pubs/2014handbooks/aos/index-byfaculty.html) give degrees (by level) and their units. Notice the parameters of [this search](http://monash.edu/pubs/2014handbooks/aos/search). Don't assume only one faculty offers a degree or unit.

Identify tables by fill-in-the-(named-)blank statements that you want to make about an application situation-

```
[unit] is an unit entity with property ...
Unit [unit] is part of degree [degree]
```

Each parameter becomes a column; each statement becomes a table; the table holds the rows that make its statement true:

```
Unit(unit,...)
DegreeHasUnit(degree,unit)
```

The sentence expresses a "relationship" in the everyday sense. (Which is why "Entity-Relationship Modeling" is so called.) We say it is the "meaning" or "predicate" of the table. Only when you actually have such a meaning could the table be updated or interpreted. Or its properties described in an ORM. Eg that (probably) DegreeHasUnit is many:many in degees:units. Sadly ORM approaches to information modeling are typically oblivious to this.

Comment: Cheers. I think I'm headed in a productive direction. I just can't get my head around the basic sql. Mapping units -> their degrees. This would be a one-to-many right? One unit is available in several degrees.

Now I'm stuck. I have a CSV file with all the units. So Unit 123 is a part of Degrees 56, 10, 222. How do I represent that in the data file so i can then import it into postgresql?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. Many-to-many!

Comment: 1. This is not made clear in your question. Take the time and effort to say what you mean. 2. Edit your question, create an answer and accept it: contribute to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Really there isn't enough information in your question to give a very specific answer, but a general university course calendar might start out something like this:

[image: ERD]

Note that you have a lot of **many-to-many** relationships.  Degrees are conferred by faculties, but some degrees are multi-disciplinary and are conferred jointly by two faculties (or more???).  Similarly, degree programs offer many courses but those courses could easily be common to multiple degree programs.  You should also consider the fact that many courses will have one or more prerequisites.

The above model is simplistic and covers only a point in time snapshot of the calendar.  You probably want to consider extending this to include a time axis so that courses are offered in various semesters.

Comment: You're right. I've never worked with a dataset as complex as this so far, so at the outset I sort of underestimated the challenge it would be. I think my initial question makes that pretty obvious. On that note I'll spend some time trying to model these relationships properly. The graphic you've shown will definitely be helpful. I'll report back when I get a solid grounding in the task at hand. Thank you.